# remove underline from textview before getting drawing cache

Tags: android, textview, underline

I'm trying to turn a textview into an image in Android. The problem is, while the use is typing in the textView, there is an underline under the last word. The underline only goes away once the keyboard is hidden (for example, if the cancel button is pressed). I tryed hiding it manually but it doesn't help - even though I cache the text AFTER I hide the keyboard, I still see the underline in the resulting bitamp. Anyone has an idea how to solve this? This is my code:

```
 public void finishEditing() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(),0 );
    mEditText.setCursorVisible(false);

    mEditText.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap cache = mEditText.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap text = cache.copy(cache.getConfig(),true);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)).removeView(mEditText);
    m_simView.addTextBitmap(text);

}
```

Note that hiding the keyboard seems to work fine - if I comment out the creation of the bitmap, I do get the textView without the underline. It seems like there is some "waiting period" between entering the hide command, and when the keyboard really does disappear. I tryed adding a sleep or a dummy loop but that didn't help either :(
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - it's

```
someTextView.clearComposingText();
```